# How do I get the value of a custom attribute from a hyperlink?

Tags: regex, parsing, coldfusion

Using ColdFusion, how can I get the "my link alias" part out of the string below? It will always use the "alias" attribute, in case that helps.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" alias="my link alias">learn more</a>
```

Comment: `<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>` ?

Comment: That RegEx gives me the entire <a> tag, and I only need to get the alias value.

Comment: You will find it in group 1. [**demo**](http://regex101.com/r/jA4wR7)

Comment: Sorry, I need to get the "my link alias" out of that string. Thank you.

Comment: *Sigh* Why don't you check your question before posting ? Anyways use `<a.*?alias\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>.*?<\/a>` [...](http://rubular.com/r/OiixkB9yfi) Note that this will match only a double quoted alias.

Comment: That seems to work so far, but I need to run some more tests. Thanks!

Comment: I like jSoup http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-Parsing-Traversing-And-Mutating-HTML-With-ColdFusion-And-jSoup.htm

Answer (score 3):

## Description

You could use this regex which will require the `a` tag, and won't accidentally match any of the other tags which start with `a`. It will also allow either double or single quotes surrounding the attribute's value. The value of the positive lookahead here is probably lost on this particular question because we're only checking a single attribute, if you're looking to capture multiple attributes then multiple lookaheads can be used to capture the attributes in any order.

`<a\b(?=[^>]*\s\balias=(["'])((?:(?!\1)|.)*)\1)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>`

[image]

## Groups

Group 0 gets the entire string from open anchor tag through the close tag

1. gets the type of quote used so it be correctly matched when closed
2. gets the value of the alias attribute
3. gets the value between the open and close anchor tags. This covers a possible intent of [the original unedited question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17116868/revisions) from the requester before the question was edited.

## Example Match

Given input text: `<a href="http://www.google.com" alias="my link's alias">learn more</a>`

```
[0] => <a href="http://www.google.com" alias="my link's alias">learn more</a>
[1] => "
[2] => my link's alias
[3] => learn more
```

Comment: This wont handle "bob's alias". It's also more complex than it needs to be - no benefit to the lookahead nor matching past the closing quote - so could just be `<a\s[^>]*\balias=(["'])([^"']*)\1`.

Comment: Actually, that'll potentially allow `not-alias` to match, needs to be `\s` rather than `\b` - so probably wants `<a(?=\s)[^>]*\salias=(["'])([^"']*)\1`

Comment: I updated my expression to cover the edge case where an attribute name is like `text-alias`. I'm not sure what is meant by `bob's alias`. That attribute name is [illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Name) because it has a space and a single quote.

Comment: I mean `alias="bob's alias"` - i.e. the expression is excluding single quotes even when the attribute is double-quoted.

Comment: Updated expression to cover the edge case `alias="bob's alias"` and `alias='bobs "alias"'`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the `|` shouldn't be there? I'd generally use `((?s:(?!\1).)*)` - i.e. removed bar and added `s` flag to allow `.` to include newlines (unlikely, but valid) - or use `((?:[^"']++|(?!\1)["'])*)` which can improve performance (wont be significant for a short string, but can make a difference for long/repeated use).

Comment: To-may-toe, to-mah-toe. I think you're starting to split hairs here because this solution does work. Any performance differences will be indistinguishable. The 's' option to allow a `.` character to match a new line should really be included on the command and not embedded into this expression.

Comment: Suggesting how to make something work isn't splitting hairs - the alternation is separating the negative lookahead from the dot and thus preventing it from performing it's task. (Try `<a alias="my link's alias" class="wibble">learn more</a>`)

Comment: Also, curious why there's an issue with embedded flags? I've not seen (and can't find) any mention of specifying them outside the pattern being better, and afaik both cases will be resolved at compile time so don't see why it matters.

Comment: Updated to satisify the edge case presented.

Comment: Thanks everyone. While the RegEx's worked out great, I ended up implementing jsoup.

Answer (score 3):

In general, **don't use regex use [jsoup](http://jSoup.org)** (or another HTML parser) - it's basically:

```
<cfset Alias = jsoup.parse(input).select('a[alias]').attr('alias') />
```

For more info, Henry posted a [link to a blog post by Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2358-Parsing-Traversing-And-Mutating-HTML-With-ColdFusion-And-jSoup.htm), there's also a [blog post by Ray Camden](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/4/6/jsoup-adds-jQuerylike-parsing-in-Java), and if you search on SO you'll find plenty of jSoup/CF questions with useful info in them.

If you're only dealing with a string in the format you provided (i.e. just an A tag, not a whole chunk of HTML), you can potentially do it as simple as:

```
<cfset Input = '<a href="http://www.google.com" alias="my link alias">learn more</a>' />
<cfset Parts = Input.split('\salias="',2) />
<cfset Alias = ListFirst(Parts[2],'"') />
```

Or to deal with possible spaces and single or double quotes:

```
<cfset Input = '<a href="http://www.google.com" alias="my link alias">learn more</a>' />
<cfset Parts = Input.split('\salias\s*=\s*(?=["''])',2) />
<cfset Alias = ListFirst( Parts[2] , Left(Parts[2],1) ) />
```

But if you're in any way unsure about what the markup will be, use a robust HTML parser instead.

Comment: This is great! I don't know how I've never heard of jsoup before. Exactly what I needed, and then some!